# Fourier-like family total in $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Consider the Hilbert space $H=L^2(-\pi,\pi)$. A subset of $H$ is said to be **total** in $H$ if the closure of its span is the whole $H$.

For instance, the **Fourier basis** $\{e^{in x}\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is a Hilbert basis for $H$ and in particular it is total in $H$.

I am interested in families of the form $\{e^{is_n x}\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$, where $\mathcal{S}=\{s_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is a strictly increasing sequence. **Is there any easy condition on $\mathcal{S}$ which guarantees that such a family is total in $H$?** I would guess that $S$ should at least be diverging, in order to capture arbitrarily high frequencies, but I'm not sure that it is actually a necessary condition.

Of course not every increasing sequence $\mathcal{S}$ has this property. An easy counter example is any $\mathcal{S}\subsetneq \mathbb{Z}$, since the obtained family would be a proper subset of the Fourier basis. However I guess there must be some easy and quite general criterion to check whether a sequence gives rise to a family total in $H$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that.  Now: if $\{t_n\}$ is a Hilbert basis, don't we have $t_a-t_b\in\mathbb Z$ whenever $a\ne b$?

Comment: Is it necessary? I'm not interested in orthogonality of the basis (maybe I'm actually wrong with the notation and Hilbert basis implies orthonormal basis.. In such a case I should edit)

Comment: I don't think the term "Hilbert basis" is used much in this context, but I would have understood it as orthonormal basis, too. It's probably best if you clarify which conditions exactly you want.

Comment: Ok, I will stick with a family spanning the whole space (that's actually what I'm looking for). Thank you all for pointing out that the question was unclear.

Comment: A wild guess is that Q- linear combinations of the  $s_n$ have to span Z. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_theorem

Answer (score 2):

This is a classical and widely studied question. See the answers to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/224001/completeness-of-nonharmonic-fourier-series.

Roughly speaking, you get totality if $s_n$ grows slower than the Fourier basis (i.e. less than linearly with rate $1/(2\pi)$)